# Aligining "Three line" txt with indentation in html

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I need to create text of which each line consists of actually three lines: the first line being latin text, the second a number and the third german text. The attached snippet does mostly what I want.

However, the text is structured in sections. In my sample, these would be sections 1 and 2, which are introduced by an orange colored large number.
Now, I would  like the orange numbers to stand out in that the text is all equally right intended. The text should look like this

```
1  foo  bar  baz
   x    y    z
   Hans Kurt Paul

   xyz  bla  etc
   a    b    c
   Stak Bort Nehm

2  .... ....
```

Is this somehow possible with html and css (but if possible without JavaScript)?

```css
.container {
  width: 30em;
}
.box {
  float: left; 
  padding: 0.25em;
  height: 5em;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}
.l1, .l2, .l3 {
  display: block;
}
.l2 {
  color: #bbf; 
  font-size: 0.9em
}
.item {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #f70;
}
.break {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
     <span class='box'><span class='item'>1</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Lorem</span><span class='l2'>1</span><span class='l3'>Dies</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>ipsum</span><span class='l2'>2</span><span class='l3'>ist</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>sapientem</span><span class='l2'>3</span><span class='l3'>ein</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>ne</span><span class='l2'>4</span><span class='l3'>Beispiel</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>neque</span><span class='l2'>5</span><span class='l3'>für</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>dolor</span><span class='l2'>6</span><span class='l3'>einen</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>erat,</span><span class='l2'>7</span><span class='l3'>Blindtext,</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>eros</span><span class='l2'>8</span><span class='l3'>der</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>solet</span><span class='l2'>9</span><span class='l3'>auf</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>invidunt</span><span class='l2'>10</span><span class='l3'>deutsch</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>duo</span><span class='l2'>11</span><span class='l3'>geschrieben</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Quisque</span><span class='l2'>12</span><span class='l3'>ist.</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>aliquid</span><span class='l2'>13</span><span class='l3'>Es</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>leo.</span><span class='l2'>14</span><span class='l3'>gibt</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Pretium</span><span class='l2'>15</span><span class='l3'>noch</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>patrioque</span><span class='l2'>16</span><span class='l3'>viele</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>sociis</span><span class='l2'>17</span><span class='l3'>weitere</span></span>
     <div class='break'></div>

     <span class='box'><span class='item'>2</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Fringilla</span><span class='l2'>43</span><span class='l3'>Mit</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>lucilius</span><span class='l2'>44</span><span class='l3'>brausender</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>mel</span><span class='l2'>45</span><span class='l3'>Geschwindigkeit</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>adipiscing</span><span class='l2'>46</span><span class='l3'>war</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>rebum.</span><span class='l2'>47</span><span class='l3'>der</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Sit</span><span class='l2'>48</span><span class='l3'>Titel</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>nulla</span><span class='l2'>49</span><span class='l3'>des</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Integer</span><span class='l2'>50</span><span class='l3'>neuen</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>ad</span><span class='l2'>51</span><span class='l3'>Boots</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>volumus,</span><span class='l2'>52</span><span class='l3'>in</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>dicta</span><span class='l2'>53</span><span class='l3'>naher</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>scriptorem</span><span class='l2'>54</span><span class='l3'>Ferne,</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>viderer</span><span class='l2'>55</span><span class='l3'>weshalb</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>lobortis</span><span class='l2'>56</span><span class='l3'>sich</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>est</span><span class='l2'>57</span><span class='l3'>der</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Utinam,</span><span class='l2'>58</span><span class='l3'>Briefträger</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>enim</span><span class='l2'>59</span><span class='l3'>einen</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>commune</span><span class='l2'>60</span><span class='l3'>roten</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>corrumpit</span><span class='l2'>61</span><span class='l3'>Mantel</span></span>
```

Comment: you can adjust the html ?

Comment: What do you mean by *adjusting the html*?

Comment: I mean chaging the HTML structure

Comment: Yes, the html is under my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the html structure for that:
I have do some change in html

1. First add div to wrap 1st box content and position relative to this
2. Add position absolute to first span which have Number 1,2,....

```css
.container {
  width: 30em;
}
.box {
  float: left; 
  padding: 0.25em;
  height: 5em;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}
.l1, .l2, .l3 {
  display: block;
}
.l2 {
  color: #bbf; 
  font-size: 0.9em
}
.item {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #f70;
}
.break {
  clear:both;
}
.main-box {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: table;
}
.main-box .item {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="main-box">
     <span class='item'>1</span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Lorem</span><span class='l2'>1</span><span class='l3'>Dies</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>ipsum</span><span class='l2'>2</span><span class='l3'>ist</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>sapientem</span><span class='l2'>3</span><span class='l3'>ein</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>ne</span><span class='l2'>4</span><span class='l3'>Beispiel</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>neque</span><span class='l2'>5</span><span class='l3'>für</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>dolor</span><span class='l2'>6</span><span class='l3'>einen</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>erat,</span><span class='l2'>7</span><span class='l3'>Blindtext,</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>eros</span><span class='l2'>8</span><span class='l3'>der</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>solet</span><span class='l2'>9</span><span class='l3'>auf</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>invidunt</span><span class='l2'>10</span><span class='l3'>deutsch</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>duo</span><span class='l2'>11</span><span class='l3'>geschrieben</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Quisque</span><span class='l2'>12</span><span class='l3'>ist.</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>aliquid</span><span class='l2'>13</span><span class='l3'>Es</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>leo.</span><span class='l2'>14</span><span class='l3'>gibt</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Pretium</span><span class='l2'>15</span><span class='l3'>noch</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>patrioque</span><span class='l2'>16</span><span class='l3'>viele</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>sociis</span><span class='l2'>17</span><span class='l3'>weitere</span></span>
     </div>
     <div class='break'></div>
     <div class="main-box">
     <span class='item'>2</span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Fringilla</span><span class='l2'>43</span><span class='l3'>Mit</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>lucilius</span><span class='l2'>44</span><span class='l3'>brausender</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>mel</span><span class='l2'>45</span><span class='l3'>Geschwindigkeit</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>adipiscing</span><span class='l2'>46</span><span class='l3'>war</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>rebum.</span><span class='l2'>47</span><span class='l3'>der</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Sit</span><span class='l2'>48</span><span class='l3'>Titel</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>nulla</span><span class='l2'>49</span><span class='l3'>des</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Integer</span><span class='l2'>50</span><span class='l3'>neuen</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>ad</span><span class='l2'>51</span><span class='l3'>Boots</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>volumus,</span><span class='l2'>52</span><span class='l3'>in</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>dicta</span><span class='l2'>53</span><span class='l3'>naher</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>scriptorem</span><span class='l2'>54</span><span class='l3'>Ferne,</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>viderer</span><span class='l2'>55</span><span class='l3'>weshalb</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>lobortis</span><span class='l2'>56</span><span class='l3'>sich</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>est</span><span class='l2'>57</span><span class='l3'>der</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Utinam,</span><span class='l2'>58</span><span class='l3'>Briefträger</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>enim</span><span class='l2'>59</span><span class='l3'>einen</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>commune</span><span class='l2'>60</span><span class='l3'>roten</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>corrumpit</span><span class='l2'>61</span><span class='l3'>Mantel</span></span>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is without adjusting the HTML, this CSS is pretty static in that the orange number will overflow if it is wider then 40px... It would be much cleaner if you could adjust the HTML, put each part that starts with the orange number in a seperate div...

```css
.container {
  width: 30em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.box {
  float: left; 
  padding: 0.25em;
  height: 5em;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}
.container .box:first-child,
.container .break + .box {
  margin-left: -40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}
.l1, .l2, .l3 {
  display: block;
}
.l2 {
  color: #bbf; 
  font-size: 0.9em
}
.item {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #f70;
}
.break {
  clear:both;
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% + 40px + 0.25em);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
     <span class='box'><span class='item'>1</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Lorem</span><span class='l2'>1</span><span class='l3'>Dies</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>ipsum</span><span class='l2'>2</span><span class='l3'>ist</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>sapientem</span><span class='l2'>3</span><span class='l3'>ein</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>ne</span><span class='l2'>4</span><span class='l3'>Beispiel</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>neque</span><span class='l2'>5</span><span class='l3'>für</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>dolor</span><span class='l2'>6</span><span class='l3'>einen</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>erat,</span><span class='l2'>7</span><span class='l3'>Blindtext,</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>eros</span><span class='l2'>8</span><span class='l3'>der</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>solet</span><span class='l2'>9</span><span class='l3'>auf</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>invidunt</span><span class='l2'>10</span><span class='l3'>deutsch</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>duo</span><span class='l2'>11</span><span class='l3'>geschrieben</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Quisque</span><span class='l2'>12</span><span class='l3'>ist.</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>aliquid</span><span class='l2'>13</span><span class='l3'>Es</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>leo.</span><span class='l2'>14</span><span class='l3'>gibt</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Pretium</span><span class='l2'>15</span><span class='l3'>noch</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>patrioque</span><span class='l2'>16</span><span class='l3'>viele</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>sociis</span><span class='l2'>17</span><span class='l3'>weitere</span></span>
     <div class='break'></div>

     <span class='box'><span class='item'>2</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Fringilla</span><span class='l2'>43</span><span class='l3'>Mit</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>lucilius</span><span class='l2'>44</span><span class='l3'>brausender</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>mel</span><span class='l2'>45</span><span class='l3'>Geschwindigkeit</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>adipiscing</span><span class='l2'>46</span><span class='l3'>war</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>rebum.</span><span class='l2'>47</span><span class='l3'>der</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Sit</span><span class='l2'>48</span><span class='l3'>Titel</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>nulla</span><span class='l2'>49</span><span class='l3'>des</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Integer</span><span class='l2'>50</span><span class='l3'>neuen</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>ad</span><span class='l2'>51</span><span class='l3'>Boots</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>volumus,</span><span class='l2'>52</span><span class='l3'>in</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>dicta</span><span class='l2'>53</span><span class='l3'>naher</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>scriptorem</span><span class='l2'>54</span><span class='l3'>Ferne,</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>viderer</span><span class='l2'>55</span><span class='l3'>weshalb</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>lobortis</span><span class='l2'>56</span><span class='l3'>sich</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>est</span><span class='l2'>57</span><span class='l3'>der</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>Utinam,</span><span class='l2'>58</span><span class='l3'>Briefträger</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>enim</span><span class='l2'>59</span><span class='l3'>einen</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>commune</span><span class='l2'>60</span><span class='l3'>roten</span></span>
     <span class='box'><span class='l1'>corrumpit</span><span class='l2'>61</span><span class='l3'>Mantel</span></span>
```